# Add missing definition in interface (@types/check-types)

Tags: typescript

This valid part

```
assert.in(name, ['values', 'some',])
```

is causing a typescript error:

```
Property 'in' does not exist on type 'ExtendWithAssert<CheckTypePredicates> & ExtendWithAssert<Pick<CheckType, "not" | "maybe">> & AssertFunction'.
```

How do I extend type definitions?
I'm using `@types/check-types`, but in that definition (index.d.ts) this line is missing:

```
interface CheckType {
    // ...
    in(a: any, value: any[]): boolean; // <-- add this
}
type CheckTypePredicates = Pick<
    CheckType,
    // ...
    | "in" // <-- add this
>;
```

**Update**

The PR has been accepted...

Comment: Why not make a PR or issue so this gets fixed for everyone?

Comment: @kelsny I did that, but I don't know how to write the test: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/66800

Comment: You have a test case _in this post_ for the types - code that should type check, but fails without your patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TLDR;

Your only options are to declare your own `check-types` module or create a PR to get the definitely typed ones modified (which you have done already). I'd say go with the PR option as that'll help others as well.

### Trying to Extend Types

In Typescript, you can use [declaration merging (module augmentation)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to add new types to a module types. However, in case of definitely typed types of a module, it's not possible to augment them through definitely typed definitions, one needs to declare a module with the name of the package (`check-types` in your case).

So, if you wish to ***extend*** types from the definitely typed type definitions, you'll have to do something along the lines of -

1. Create an `index.d.ts` file at the root of the project.
2. Add the `index.d.ts` file path to your `tsconfig.json`'s `typeRoots` or `include` to make them available globally.
3. declare the `check-types` module in the `index.d.ts` file like so -

```ts
declare module "check-types" {
  import * as CheckTypes from "@types/check-types";

  type ModifiedModuleTypes = typeof CheckTypes & {
    assert: (typeof CheckTypes)["assert"] & {
      in: (a: any, value: any[]) => boolean;
    };
  };

  const c: ModifiedModuleTypes;
  export default c;
  export const assert: ModifiedModuleTypes["assert"];
}
```

Although this will make the error go away, it's not a complete solution, because we'll have to add definitions for all the types, to get correct types everywhere, and we'd rather copy everything from the definitely typed definitions and modify them as per our requirements for usage and get rid of the `@types/check-types` package from the dependencies.

With that being the case, it's either not to use the definitely typed definitions or make a PR to get them modified (which you already have done).

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

This is what is written in the [`index.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bd35184033d061f66e1c20eff33c5f842ef24f28/types/check-types/index.d.ts#L82) you have referred to. So it is indeed a module.

```
export = check;
```

So any interface/type declared here is not available to the global namespace. The only thing available outside this modules is the contents of `check` and hence the method `assert` is available to you.

Remember namespaces can span multiple files not modules.

From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#:%7E:text=A%20key%20feature%20of%20modules,exported%20symbols%20in%20a%20namespace.):

> A key feature of modules in TypeScript is that two different modules will never contribute names to the same scope. Because the consumer of a module decides what name to assign it, there’s no need to proactively wrap up the exported symbols in a namespace.

Also, the folder `@types/check-types` do not declare any namespace. So any point of declaration merging is moot, as the types (since they are a part of a module) are not available in any other namespace.

The type of a variable is inferred at initialisation (as you would have seen multiple times in VSCode or any typescript playground). The type of `assert` (exported as a constituent of `check`) is already defined.

Here is a github [discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7148#issuecomment-270502523) for the same problem for some other library.

There is no great way to do it. If you are okay using a different export for now, you can create a new file called `extended-check-types`:

```
import { assert as oldAssert } from 'check-types';

type NewAssertType = typeof oldAssert & {
  in: (name: string, list: string[]) => void;
};

const assert = oldAssert as NewAssertType;

assert.prototype.in = (name: string, list: string[]) => {
  return list.indexOf(name) > -1;
};

export { assert };
```

Use `import { assert } from 'extended-check-types';`